# Avro Schema definition for ObjectMap Map<String,Object>

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka, avro

I am new to Avro serialization. My requirement is to serialize a class having a Map<String, Object> as its property. This object could be any type of class like Student, Teacher, Principal.

```
class Payload
{
   private string transactionNo,
   private Map<String,Object> map,
}
```

Please suggest to me a way to write a schema for the above scenario.